# Extjs: Override pivot.plugin.configurator setting's field

Tags: extjs, overriding

I'm trying to override the pivot.plugin.configurator so i can change the Setting's texts, i already override the language of the configurator itself doing:

```html
    override: 'Ext.pivot.plugin.configurator.Panel',
    panelAllFieldsTitle:'Todos os Campos',
    panelAggFieldsTitle:'Valores',
    panelTopFieldsTitle:'Colunas',
```

But i can't find a way to change the texts of the Settings (when the user click on the cog in the configurator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the [`title` config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/src/Settings.js.html) of the [Ext.pivot.plugin.configurator.window.Settings](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.pivot.plugin.configurator.window.Settings.html) class in order to achieve this.

**EDIT**

It seems that title does not get overridden like so, although other configs do. One workaround is to override the `initComponent` method and set the title there:

```
initComponent() {
    this.callParent();
    this.setTitle('DESIRED TITLE');
},
```

Comment: Perfect, but for some unkwnonw reason the only value i can't change is "title', i could change all the other fields.